# mt19337 in std does not name a type

Tags: c++

The problem is in a single line. The library clearly says random has a type mt19337.

```
#include <random>

class Util{
    std::mt19337 generator;
};
```

Compiled with
    g++ -std=c++11 -c util.cpp

The output is

```
util.cpp:4:7: error: ‘mt19337’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
std::mt19337 generator;
   ^
```

G++ configuration

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04)
```

Comment: You have a typo. It is `mt19937`.

Answer (score 6):

Typo: that's `std::mt19937`, not `std::mt19337`!

Comment: I will go ahead and put my face in my palm.

Comment: @arynaq Call it facepalm for short. :P

Comment: So I can't edit your answer because I wouldn't change the required 6 characters, but could you please remove the `std::` for the sake of consistency? :)

Comment: @Siguza That would not be a useful edit.

Comment: @Siguza: Just to annoy you, I'll do the opposite ;)